# How to solve issue with adding nuget packet to .net core project in os x?

Tags: .net, sql-server, macos, openssl, nuget

ASP.NET Core project in os x connects to MSSQL.

Exception is:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A connection was successfully
>   established with the server, but then an error occurred during the
>   pre-login handshake. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 31 -
>   Encryption(ssl/tls) handshake failed) --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Crypto'
>   threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type
>   initializer for 'CryptoInitializer' threw an exception. --->
>   System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL
>   'System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl': The specified module
>   could not be found.

I added packet

> System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl

But after I add I have the same issue. I can't find a packet with "native" `System.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl, can find System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl only.`

How to solve this issue?.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was correct packet

> System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl

I had to install the OpenSSL as described in the tutorial at https://www.microsoft.com/net/core#macos